# Dealing with underscores in `\section` and similar

Tags: latex3

The code below doesn't compile **logically**:

```
Verbatim-like command '\test' illegal in argument...
```

Is there a way to "fix" this? If not, can I at least use a `m` parameter, and then replace all the underscores by `::` for example, like if the user has typed `\section{\test{txt::example}}`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{v}{%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\texttt{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{\test{txt_example}}

The smallest \test{txt_example} in the world.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a documented restriction. But what would be the reason of defining `\test` that way and then asking to replace `_` with `::` as a fallback possibility? My impression is that you want to do something else.

Comment: I am working on [jinjaNG](https://github.com/bc-tools/for-dev/tree/main/jinjaNG). I need to type `\test{txt_example}` in a template file such as to build a new one from data. During the templating phase, it is not a problem to see `txt::example` instead of `txt_example`. One short use case [here](https://github.com/bc-tools/for-dev/tree/main/jinjaNG/contribute/api/dsl/latex/usecases/no-param-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a regex replacement.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {
  \formattest { \projetmbc_test:n { #1 } }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__projetmbc_test_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_test:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__projetmbc_test_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { _ } { \c{textunderscore} } \l__projetmbc_test_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__projetmbc_test_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\formattest}{m}{%
  \textcolor{red!90!blue}{\fbox{\ttfamily #1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{\test{txt_example}}

The smallest \test{txt_example} in the world.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I should at least try this by myself... I will point to this post in my code.

Comment: What is the need to use `cs_new_protected`?

Comment: @projetmbc The function performs an assignment, hence it should be protected.